# Socket.io: How to deal with an authenticated client who opens two windows?

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

I'm coding an HTML5 game server. The server contains a list of matches, and when a user joins one of the matches they are able to see the progress of the game, as well as chat with other users etc.

When a user joins a match the server looks in their session object for a 'userid' string. The userid string refers to a user object. If it's not found, a new user object is created and the 'userid' string is added to the session object.

This allows the user to have connections to multiple games using multiple tabs/windows, whilst still displaying the same username, display picture in each window.

The problem now is dealing with having the same user connected to the same match more than once. If the user has two windows connected to the same game, I want them to see the exact same thing on both windows - sort of like Facebook chat.

Currently, when a user connects to a match, a new 'connection' object is created, and on this object I handle the socket events etc.

What I was hoping to be able to do was to handle the events of multiple sockets using the same event handler function. The only thing stopping me is that the socket events do not have an 'owner' argument. With no reference to the socket receiving the message, I can't broadcast a message out to all sockets excluding the one that received a message.

SocketIO Rooms do not meet my requirements either, because there are no events for messages received on a channel.

What I'm instead being forced to consider is having both a connection object and a participant object, where each participant has multiple connections. This feels very bloated to me.

Another option would be to try and force myself to write using spaghetti code and take advantage of closures etc.

Really need some advice from someone who has been in a similar situation.

Comment: What do you mean by "there are no events for messages received on a channel"? If you call .send('foo') on a channel, that will cause a 'message' event to be emitted (this happens the same way on both channel-namespace and the default namespace). If you need custom events on that channel, I'm confused as to why you believe that attaching them is impossible? Your exact requirements seem kind of ambiguous, but have you looked at the 'broadcast' method for resolving "broadcast[ing] a message out to all sockets excluding the one that received a message"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Productish Solution:** Force the user to use one window.

If the user is already connected and since the server knows this, have the second window display a dialog like,

> You already have another window open with AwesomeGame. Please use that window or click the button below.
>
> <kbd>Use this window</kbd>

If the user clicks the button, send a message over SocketIO claiming that connection as the one that represents the user. The server would then notify all prior connections that they have been superseded.

**Engineerish Solution:** Provide each client with a token they can use to authenticate to the server using SocketIO.

When the HTML is generated and served, include the user's ID on the page and sign it with a secret key known by the server. For example, our token looks like:

```
<user id>|<salt>|<SHA1 hash of uid + salt + secret key>
```

When a client connects, ignore all messages until the client has authenticated by providing the signed token. The server can break apart the token and verify that that SocketIO client indeed represents that user.

On the server, use a pubsub system to subscribe open SocketIO connections with user IDs. When a message is bound for a specific user, publish it to the user ID.